# How to make table with horizontal scrolling with tailwindcss 2.1?

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to make table with horizontal scrolling for its content and
I try to use `whitespace-nowrap` class for table cells which have long content and
overflow-x-auto for all the table, like:

```html
    <div class="editor_listing_wrapper_bix_width">


        <table class=" overflow-x-auto p-1 m-1 d2">
            <thead class="bg-gray-700 border-b-2 border-t-2 border-gray-300">
            <tr>
                <th class="w-1/12 py-2">Id</th>
                <th class="w-4/12 py-2">Name</th>
                <th class="w-4/12 py-2">Description</th>
                <th class="w-1/12 py-2"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            <tr>

                <td>1</td>
                <td class="whitespace-nowrap">
                    Laptops
                    <small class="pl-2 pt-1">
                        ( Used in 2 ad(s) )
                    </small>
                </td>

                <td class="whitespace-nowrap p-1">Laptops description Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consectetur
                    adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
                    aliqua....
                </td>
```

But looks like  horizontal scrolling is for all area, not for my table

Pls, take look at pen: https://codepen.io/sergeynilov/pen/eYgjVgM

I use tailwindcss 2.1.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decision was in setting overflow-x-auto in wrapping div:

```html
<div class="overflow-x-auto">
    <table class="editor_listing_table">
```

With custom class defined:

```css
.editor_listing_table {
    @apply w-full p-2 m-1;
}
```

That provided the functionality I needed!

Answer (score 1):

I have found `<table>` to be limited with flexibility. I usually convert it to a simple `<div>` and then move forward accordingly. Checkout this [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/UYXj7049vC).

```html
<div>
  <div id="header" class="flex items-center bg-gray-100 h-10 px-4">
    <div class="w-2/12 font-semibold">Id</div>
    <div class="w-2/12 font-semibold">Name</div>
    <div class="w-6/12 font-semibold">Description</div>
    <div class="w-2/12 font-semibold">Actions</div>
  </div>

  <div id="body" class="px-4 space-y-4">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="w-2/12">1</div>
      <div class="w-2/12">John</div>
      <div class="w-6/12 max-h-20 overflow-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem corporis sed, porro saepe rerum illum minus ipsa tenetur animi sint cupiditate dolorem! Laboriosam, aperiam expedita aliquid impedit provident non corporis?Reiciendis tempore soluta nisi ratione voluptates cupiditate. Deserunt possimus repellendus repellat, nobis maiores accusantium minima? Temporibus commodi iusto necessitatibus, rerum vel maxime totam veniam, natus quaerat voluptate perferendis maiores porro.</div>
      <div class="w-2/12">Edit</div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex">
      <div class="w-2/12">2</div>
      <div class="w-2/12">Jane</div>
      <div class="w-6/12 max-h-20 overflow-auto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, necessitatibus vitae itaque maxime cupiditate dicta maiores, assumenda animi unde sapiente deserunt, repellat commodi distinctio corrupti! Esse est error corrupti repudiandae. Aliquam expedita cupiditate, eligendi voluptate consectetur illo ea iure excepturi perspiciatis, ut deleniti ullam. Illum quidem ea hic animi nemo, vitae adipisci nesciunt neque praesentium dolor expedita nulla quaerat itaque? Sint necessitatibus dolor ab sed. Fugit ab architecto sit voluptate, officia similique explicabo, quia earum iure, aliquam hic. Nostrum voluptatum beatae ullam porro minus voluptate debitis nemo expedita, quasi deleniti.</div>
      <div class="w-2/12">Edit</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very interesting decision, but it is different I search